# Filter date range using jQuery UI calendars in AngularJS data-bound table

Tags: angularjs, filter, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a series of HTML tables which pull data from JSON sources.  These are tabbed.  They work fine and can be seen in the fiddle here:

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nA28B/1/.

What I need to do now though is use the date range inputs (which are integrated as jQuery UI datepickers) to filter the data in the tables by the date column.  I'm new to AngularJS and the integration with the jQuery UI datepickers particularly has taken this way over my head and I'm struggling to find the solution.

I've tried adding an ng-change attribute to the date inputs but can't even get this to fire a simple alert - possibly I've not set up controllers in the correct places (I've tried creating a new controller around the filter inputs to no avail)?

The code for this is pretty lengthy but quite straight forward, as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <h2>Tabs:</h2>
    <div class="tabs" ng-init="selected=1">
        <a href="" title="" class="tab selected" rel="tab1" ng:click="selected=1" ng:class="{'active' : selected==1 }">Purchases</a>
        <a href="" title="" class="tab" rel="tab2" ng:click="selected=2" ng:class="{'active' : selected==2 }">Products on sale</a>
        <a href="" title="" class="tab" rel="tab3" ng:click="selected=3" ng:class="{'active' : selected==3 }">Last 30 days sales</a>
    </div>
    <h2>Filters:</h2>
    <div>
        <label for="fromDate">From date:</label> <input type="text" name="fromDate" value="from date..." ng-model="dateFrom" datepicker />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="toDate">To date:</label> <input type="text" name="toDate" value="to date..." ng-model="dateTo" datepicker />
    </div>
    <div class="selected" ng-controller="PurchasesCtrl" ng:show="selected == 1">
        <h3>Purchases:</h3>
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="first">
                <th class="first">Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="purchase in purchases.data" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class="{'last':$last}">
                <td class="first">{{purchase.date}}</td>
                <td>{{purchase.text}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="selected" ng-controller="SaleProductsCtrl" ng:show="selected == 2">
        <h3>Sale products:</h3>                         
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="first">
                <th class="first">Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="saleProduct in saleProducts.data" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class="{'last':$last}">
                <td class="first">{{saleProduct.date}}</td>
                <td>{{saleProduct.text}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="selected" ng-controller="Sale30DaysCtrl" ng:show="selected == 3">
        <h3>Sale 30 days:</h3>
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="first">
                <th class="first">Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="sale30Day in sale30Days.data" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class="{'last':$last}">
                <td class="first">{{sale30Day.date}}</td>
                <td>{{sale30Day.text}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.factory("Purchases", function(){
    var Purchases = {};
    Purchases.data = [
        {
            date: "10/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        },
        {
            date: "05/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        },
        {
            date: "20/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        }
    ];
    return Purchases;
});

function PurchasesCtrl($scope, Purchases){
    $scope.purchases = Purchases;   
}




myApp.factory("SaleProducts", function(){
    var SaleProducts = {};
    SaleProducts.data = [
        {
            date: "10/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        },
        {
            date: "28/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        }
    ];
    return SaleProducts;
});

function SaleProductsCtrl($scope, SaleProducts){
    $scope.saleProducts = SaleProducts;   
}




myApp.factory("Sale30Days", function(){
    var Sale30Days = {};
    Sale30Days.data = [
        {
            date: "06/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        },
        {
            date: "08/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        },
        {
            date: "21/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        },
        {
            date: "20/05/2012",
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor"
        }
    ];
    return Sale30Days;
});

function Sale30DaysCtrl($scope, Sale30Days){
    $scope.sale30Days = Sale30Days;   
}


myApp.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function () {
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone set me on the right track with this please?  I've tried everything I can think of but I've reached my AngularJS limit!

**EDIT:**

I've simplified the example just to try to get the basic date filtering working, so I can then get the tabs etc hooked up afterwards.  Here's a simplified fiddle:

**SIMPLIFIED FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/bY3YL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem was quite simple, your input was outside of you controller, so even though you would had used `ng-change`, it would had never been called.

I fixed your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jjperezaguinaga/bY3YL/2/). I also added the filtering function; it's only for the From Date input field, but I think you might figure the To Date one by yourself.

```
$scope.onChangeFromDate = function() {
    var fromDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $scope.dateFrom);
    angular.forEach($scope.purchases.data, function(purchase){
        var purchaseDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', purchase.date);
        if(purchaseDate.getTime() < fromDate.getTime()) {
            purchase.filtered = true;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like it works great, but how would I handle this in my original example where I have three controllers?  Do I need to refactor this so the whole thing just uses a single controller, or could I have a controller around just the filters that would work?

Comment: Actually, the filtering in this solution only works the first time.  The second time it doesn't seem to apply the filter to the original data set.

Comment: Forgot to reset the filter, updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jjperezaguinaga/bY3YL/3/)